# Password protected excel as mail attachment

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have created a jar for sending mail using java. I have to attach an excel file with mail. Am using HSSF for creating worksheet. But I need to encrypt the attachment with password. I succeeded. But when I open the attachment directly from mail through Outlook it's not asking password. and when I copy to any folder and then if I try to open , it works properly. Can anyone, please help?

```
public static void main(final String... args) throws Exception {     

        String fname = "D:\\Mail\\Sample.xls";

        FileInputStream fileInput = null;       
        BufferedInputStream bufferInput = null;      
        POIFSFileSystem poiFileSystem = null;    
        FileOutputStream fileOut = null;

        try {           

            fileInput = new FileInputStream(fname);         
            bufferInput = new BufferedInputStream(fileInput);            
            poiFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(bufferInput);            

            Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword("secret");            
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(poiFileSystem, true);            
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);           

            HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
            Cell cell = row.createCell(0);

            cell.setCellValue("THIS WORKS!"); 

            fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fname);
            workbook.writeProtectWorkbook(Biff8EncryptionKey.getCurrentUserPassword(), "");
            workbook.write(fileOut);

            File file = new File("D:\\Mail\\Sample.xls");

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            try {
                for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
                    bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); 
                    System.out.println("read " + readNum + " bytes,");
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
            byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();   

// Code for sending mail         

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());      

        } finally {         

              try {            

                  bufferInput.close();     

              } catch (IOException ex) {

                  System.out.println(ex.getMessage());     

              }    

              try {            

                  fileOut.close();     

              } catch (IOException ex) {

                  System.out.println(ex.getMessage());     

              } 
        }       

    }
```

Comment: Could you post the code you wrote to create and password-protect the excel, and to send it via email? Without code, this question looks very much like an MS Office problem rather than a programming one.

Comment: Sure... Please check it...

Comment: Where is the code for the encyption? The call to `writeProtectWorkbook()` just sets the writeprotect flag for the workbook. It does not encrypt. From the doc: "protect a workbook with a password (not encypted, just sets writeprotect flags and the password."

Comment: Oh, I see. IMHO the POI API is really horrible with regards to this...

Comment: yes, i need to set a password for the attachment so that when the receiver opens the file it should ask for password to enter. I tried with the above code, it works fine, but not when it send as attachment in mail

Answer (score 1):

Method `HSSFWorkbook.writeProtectWorkbook(...)` is only meant to protect the workbook from being written to / modified.
If you try to open it in read+write mode (default in Windows folders), it will ask you for the password.
But if you open it in read-only mode, which is what Outlook does with attachments, it will let you view the contents since you can't write over them and thus you don't need the write password.
That's the reason you can view (but not edit) it in Outlook but not when you open it from a folder.

I don't know if the latest version of Apache POI supports full password protection for an HSSFWorkBook (a quick Google search says it doesn't, but who knows).

If it doesn't, you can work around this problem by making a password-protected ZIP file with the excel in it, and attaching the ZIP file instead.